# Pandas: How to handle pylint errors introduced by DataFrame.set_index's annotations in 1.5.0 release

Tags: python, pandas, pylint

The annotations of dataframe's set_index method leads to pylint throwing an error, when accessing columns by []-notation.

This is because pylint does not know, Nones are returned in inplace=True case only. This could be worked around by accessing by `df.A` but this would fail in inplace=True case either way. Can you please advise, how to best handle this issue?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{"A": 1, "B": 2}]).set_index("B")
print(df.A)  # this wokrs
print(df['A'])  # this throws an pylint error
```

Answer (score 0):

First, some more information :

- the `set_index()` method returns `( DataFrame | None )`
- the type() of `df.A` and `df['A']` are both `panda.core.series.Series`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{"A": 1, "B": 2}]).set_index("B")
print(df.A)  # pylint: "A" is not a member of "None"
print(df['A'])  # pylint: Object of type "None" is not scriptable
```

As `pylint` don't know if your indexing returns a value or not, it complains about it, even if at runtime, for this particular case, everything is ok.

You can decompose your statement in 2 lines, and replace the index inplace, so `df` will remains a `DataFrame` :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{"A": 1, "B": 2}])
df.set_index("B", inplace=True)  # df is still a DataFrame
print(df.A)  # No problem
print(df['A'])  # No problem
```